# Problem with `sudo airmon-ng start wlan0`

Tags: wireless, command-line, network-manager

I have Ubuntu 14.04 on Macbook Pro. I've tried to run:

```
sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
```

then the result was:

```
Found 5 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!

PID Name
899 avahi-daemon
904 avahi-daemon
978 NetworkManager
1298    wpa_supplicant
4408    dhclient

Process with PID 4408 (dhclient) is running on interface wlan0

Interface        Chipset                    Driver
wlan0             **Unknown**   wl - [phy0]mon0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
                (monitor mode enabled on mon0)
```

Comment: So, which part from the following paragraph is not clear: *"Found 5 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!"* ?